# How can I select the features and train with support vector machine algorithms?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, feature-selection

I have heart data set which are include features such as age,sex,cp,trestbps,chol,fbs,restecg,thalach,exang,oldpeak,slope,ca,thal,Target Variable.Each of data has numeric value.

I want to train the data with Support Vector machine algorithm.

```
#read data
setwd("C:/Users/sevvalayse.yurtekin/Desktop/SevvalAyse_Yurtekin")
data_heart = read.csv("heart_disease_dataset.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
data_heart

#split randomly test and train data. 75% train, 25% test.
ind<- sample(2, nrow(data_heart), replace = T, prob = c(0.75,0.25))
train<-data_heart[ind==1, ]
test<-data_heart[ind==2, ]

classifier = svm(formula = age ~.,
                 data = train,
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'linear')
classifier
```

This is my code. I split the data. But how can I train? How can I decide the features? Or Can I take and use all features? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you gave you're using all the other variables to predict age, this is what `formula = age ~.` means.

There are two ways to specify the features and target variable, either you use the formula parameter, for example:

```
classifier <- svm(formula = target ~ age + sex + cp + trestbps + chol + fbs,
                 data = train,
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'linear')
```

or you provide the features and target separately as the `x` and `y` parameters (respectively) for `svm` (see [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/e1071/versions/1.7-4/topics/svm)), for example:

```
classifier <- svm(x = train[,c('age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs')],
                 y = train[,'target'],
                 type = 'C-classification',
                 kernel = 'linear')
```

If you want to use all the features, you can just use the shortcut `target ~ .` as you did, but in your version the target variable is `age`.

The model is trained when the `svm` function is called. After that you will probably want to predict the target variable on your test set:

```
predicted <- predict(classifier, test)
```

Note that here I'm giving the full dataframe `test` because it's more convenient, but of course the `target` column is not needed.